# No visible @interace for'NSArray' declares the selector 'arrayByPerformingSelector'

Tags: iphone, ios6.1

getting error at this statement

```
NSArray * segmentTitles = [segmentedViewControllers arrayByPerformingSelector:@selector(title)];
```

error:

```
No visible @interace for'NSArray' declares the selector 'arrayByPerformingSelector'
```

declared the object of NSArray class

```
NSArray               * segmentedViewControllers;
```

Have extension class for NSArray+PerformSelector.

Any ideas to solve this error.

Will Appreciate help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added `#import "NSArray+PerformSelector.h"` to your code.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I forgot.